# Office 365 REST API create an event along with file attachment

Tags: rest, office365

I'm a beginner in implementing office 365 rest api. I want to create an event in the calendar along with a file attachment to event. I tried creating and event and then creating attachment with the event id that is generated for an event but all the invites are not updated with the newly added attachment. is there something that i need to follow to add an attachment to event.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

To add attachments for the event, we need to update the appointment(organizer) after we add the attachments.
We can modify the the body of the message to add some description for update the appointment. Here is an example for your reference:

PATCH:https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{eventid}

```
    {
    "Body": {
    "Content":"Content=<html><head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'><meta content='text/html; charset=us-ascii'></head><body>I think it will meet our requirements! add attachments</body></html>",
    "ContentType":"HTML"
            }
    }
```